# gettext for HTML or LaTeX?

Tags: html, latex, internationalization, gettext

Is there something like [`gettext`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for HTML or LaTeX? It would be great for generating simple bilingual webpages or LaTeX documents that should be kept in sync.
Is there something like that already? I guess there must be some Perl script for that, but I couldn't find one. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: It should be on topic: "software tools commonly used by programmers". I write documentation in LaTeX. I was asking for Perl scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. Translation software is problematic because of the differences in connotation and grammar from language to language. I'd imagine (though i've never used gettext) that gettext might work OK for short strings, but for a full document, you're sure to run into problems.

Comment: That's what I thought. :-(
So that means if I would like to write a small book in 2 languages, I can't do the same I'd do with a C program... I guess I have to live with that.

Comment: unless you can speak both languages fluently, I wouldn't use translation software to accomplish translation. you'd need to be able to proof the copy in it's native form.  Now, if you want to simply typeset your documents in two different languages, LaTeX is brilliant for that.

Comment: I think I found something: http://po4a.alioth.debian.org/
I'll check it out.

Comment: Thank you for your questio and answer @Jay, I'd like to translate my PhD, while being fluent in both French and English. An up-to-date link is https://po4a.org/